# Rules following a raise, then a shove for slightly more?

Tags: texas-hold-em, pre-flop

No Limit Texas Holdem
Blinds are 200/400. Player A (under the gun) calls 400. Player B raises to 1,200
Player C shoves for 2,050
Player D calls 2,050

Can player A now raise? If so, why?

Comment: Yes. He called 400, then was raised to 1200, which entitles him to reraise. Player C's all in changes the amount, but not the entitlement. Player B will NOT be allowed to raise if player A just calls, because player C's raise was incomplete.

Answer (score 2):

Since player B made a legit raise (800 or more), played A is indeed allowed to re-raise.